# facebook like button website description

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I've added a Facebook like button to [my website](http://festivals.ie/), by following [these instructions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). Basically, I added this HTML:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.festivals.ie" 
    data-send="false" data-width="100"data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"     
    data-layout="button_count">
</div>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=29208799875673";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

When the button is pressed, the following popout appears:

[image]

The popout contains some text that describes the website (circled in red). This text seems to be copied from the first non-empty  `<p>` element that appears on the page (starting from the top).

Is there a way that I can change this to something that better describes the site? I tried adding a

```
<meta name="description" content="my website description"/>
```

But it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the opengraph description meta tag. You might also want to add the title unless your page title is always what you want to appear on Facebook.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />
<meta property="og:description" content="..." />
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/ for further information.

Comment: They recommend adding the *og:title* tag in addition to the title tag